# How to redirect output from Powershell command to a text file

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to send a powershell output command to a text file. I need to add others output commands on one line when I execute a command.

In particular, I want send the output of this command:

```
Copy-Item -Verbose [fileName] -destination [path]
```

I tried to use:

```
$file = Copy-Item -Verbose [fileName] -destination [path]

add-Content $file [path] reportFile.txt
```

but the txt file is blank.

is it possibile to save the output of command "DETAILED: Execution of the "Copy file" to the destination etc...?

Comment: Read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.2#example-4-redirect-all-streams-to-a-file

Comment: You can also use the `-PassThru` switch to have access to the objects being copied.

Answer (score 2):

Redirect the `Verbose` output stream to the log file.

```
PS C:\src\t> Copy-Item -Verbose .\zzz-.txt -Destination C:\src 4>.\zzz-result.txt
PS C:\src\t> type .\zzz-result.txt
Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: C:\src\t\zzz-.txt Destination: C:\src\zzz-.txt".
```

Answer (score 2):

Read [about_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.2#example-4-redirect-all-streams-to-a-file)

If you want to redirect All Streams (including Verbose), see example:

[Example 4: Redirect all streams to a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.2#example-4-redirect-all-streams-to-a-file)

So, for your example, would be:

```
Copy-Item -Verbose [fileName] -destination [path] *> .\reportFile.txt
```

Comment: this is a good solution, but if I would to see the output on the console too?

Answer (score 2):

The other answers have already covered the stream redirection, but you can also consider using a transcript to log everything. This is obviously useful if you want to log several commands.

Example:

```
> Start-Transcript -Path "reportFile.txt"
> Copy-Item -Verbose [fileName] -destination [path]
> Stop-Transcript
```

the file `reportFile.txt` will contain detailed information on what was executed, along with the output.

By using a transcript, you don't have to bother redirecting the output of every command; you just need to make sure the command is executed within the start and the stopping of the transcript.